# Changing window title color

Tags: cocoa

How can i change the window title color of a Window. I want to change the default black

color text to some other color.

Comment: Why? This is a bad idea with no easy solution. Care to explain more of your aim?

Comment: My window background color is black so i want it to compensate it using text having some other color. Is there no solution or i have to change my back ground color only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:  http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSWindow

I found the following information:

> How can I change the color of the text
>   in the title bar? Is there an
>   NSWindowTitleBar?? I can't seem to
>   find anything on Google about this. --
>   JasonTerhorst
>
> NSTitledFrame?(private) has
>   _drawTitleStringIn:withColor: You can override this method.
>
> CocoaMovieTheater?
>   (http://www.zathras.de/) includes
>   private headers of window frame
>   classes. -- Afunishi
>
> Note that I took down MovieTheatre?
>   ages ago, but since this page seems to
>   be leading so many people to my site,
>   I put up the class that I used to do
>   custom window colors separately. Find
>   it at
>   http://www.zathras.de/angelweb/sourcecode.htm#UKCustomWindowFrame
>   . Oh, and Afunishi, please don't
>   directly link into the archives on my
>   web site, link to the sourcecode page
>   that contains a description for each
>   of them. Thanks! -- UliKusterer

However, the use of or overriding of private methods is strongly discouraged. Apple might change these at any time and your application will cease to function(!) correctly.

Your other option is to take care of all of the title bar drawing yourself, but this isn't easy.

I would suggest coming up with an alternative design and filing a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com requesting the feature, making sure to explain in great detail why it is important to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late... but I found a solution that works for me, and probably for you too.

The only problem is that the windows's content view doesn't draw outside its bounds. If it would, you simply added a NSTextView to the content view and placed it (outside the content view's bounds) where the window title would appear...

Well, just do that! And by code you simply resize the contentView's frame rect. That's it. No magic, just simple stuff.

Don't forget to anchor all your views from the window's bottom, not the top!

```
NSRect R = [self.window.contentView frame];
R.size.height += 20;
[self.window.contentView setFrame:R];
```