# Changing color of NSWindow title text

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I know this won't be a popular question and some people don't like apps that have a non-standard look, but it is useful for my application.

Is it possible to change the color of the NSWindow's titlebar text, in a "standard" non-private API way?

I know it's possible if I use private API ([as mentioned in this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453248/changing-window-title-color) but I presume it is possible to do it without private API as Pixelmator has done it and not been rejected from MAS. I know it's also possible to do it by making a borderless window and drawing everything myself, but I don't think that's how Pixelmator is doing it, because they still get all the additional bits that comes with the standard NSWindow titlebar; draggable icons, rename the window, the dropdown menu for document revisions and the fullscreen button.

Basically, I've made a black window using setBackgroundColor: but the text still comes up as black, which doesn't work on a black background.

So does anyone know a way to do this, or how Pixelmator is doing it?

Comment: I'm too lazy to try this, but I wonder what you'd get if you got the content view of the window and asked it for its superview.  Maybe you'd get nil, or maybe you'd get a root view containing other hidden things.

Comment: You get a private NSView subclass called NSThemeView. It does contain some more private views for the window close,minimise and maximise buttons, but I don't see how to access the title without using private API.

Comment: There is an article by Matt Gallagher about custom windows, you should be able to find some information there. http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html

Comment: As mentioned in the question I don't want to do a custom window

Comment: I have posted answer.  check my  [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20016023/2515572)

Answer (score 11):

Since OS X 10.10 it should be enough to change the appearance of the window to NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark

```
  window.appearance = NSAppearance(named:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)
```

Thought it's worth to mention since most of the answers you can find are out of date.

Comment: Not working with panels... "Unrecognized selector `_backstoppedByDefaultAppearance`"

Comment: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark looks great, but it seems to cause problems in my OpenGL based app... it appears to create semi-transparent window bars, and seems to use CoreAnimation crap.  I just want a simple dark NSAppearance with no frills!

Comment: The question was about NSWindow, not NSPanel.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution in Swift. It is late and I'm tired so this is probably not optimal but it works.

First, here is a function to find a view within an hierarchy, with the option to skip a specific view. (Which is useful if we are going search through `window.contentView.superview.subviews` and we want to ignore your  own views in the `contentView`)

```
func findViewInSubview(subviews: [NSView], #ignoreView: NSView, test: (NSView) -> Bool) -> NSView? {
    for v in subviews {
        if test(v) {
            return v
        } else if v != ignoreView {
            if let found = findViewInSubview(v.subviews as [NSView], ignoreView: ignoreView, test) {
                return found
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

And here is how you would use it, for example from an `NSViewController` subclass. Note that you need to do it when the window has become visible, so you can't do it in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    if let windowContentView = view.window?.contentView as? NSView {
        if let windowContentSuperView = windowContentView.superview {
            let titleView = findViewInSubview(windowContentSuperView.subviews as [NSView], ignoreView: windowContentView) { (view) -> Bool in
                // We find the title by looking for an NSTextField. You may
                // want to make this test more strict and for example also
                // check for the title string value to be sure.
                return view is NSTextField
            }
            if let titleView = titleView as? NSTextField {
                titleView.attributedStringValue = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: NSColor.redColor()])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Do note that you are playing with fire. Internals like this are unspecified for a reason.*

Comment: This works for me, however it seems like it draws the text twice. The first text is drawn normally, just as wanted, but the second one is a bit off. This gives it a really weird look. Any idea on how to solve this? [link](http://imgur.com/oYaoAeJ)

Comment: This method works for me. But you still need to set NSWindow.title before set titleView.attributedStringValue so that the title text can be correctly layout.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I do It:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface SOWindow : NSWindow
@end

@interface SOWindowFrameOverrides : NSView
@end

@implementation SOWindow

+ (void)load
{
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_currentTitleColor");
    SEL originalSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_original_currentTitleColor");
    Class frameClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSThemeFrame");

    Method m = class_getInstanceMethod(frameClass, selector);
    Method m2 = class_getInstanceMethod([SOWindowFrameOverrides class], selector);
    class_addMethod(frameClass, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(m), method_getTypeEncoding(m));
    method_exchangeImplementations(m, m2);
}

@end

@implementation SOWindowFrameOverrides

- (NSColor *)_currentTitleColor
{
    if ([self.window isKindOfClass:[SOWindow class]]) {
        return [NSColor redColor];
    } else {
        return [self _original_currentTitleColor];
    }
}

- (NSColor *)_original_currentTitleColor
{
    // will be filled in at runtime
    return nil;
}

@end
```

While the view hierarchy has changed a lot from Mavericks to Yosemite, `_currentTitleColor` has been in the API for a long time and will probably not change in the near future. Even tough method swizzling is a hacky way of doing It, I find It more elegant than traversing the view hierarchy, but that's just me.

If you want to customize the title even further, you can override `_titleTextField` on `NSThemeFrame` to return a customized text field (I have used It to change the backgroundStyle on my [F3X](https://github.com/insidegui/F3X) project).

Comment: Do you have any pointers on how to create a "fadable" title bar (like in QuicktimeX) for OS _before yosemite_. (this is trivial on yosemite+ but I specifically want to do so on mavericks and below). I saw your GRGlassWindow project that did this by creating an entirely new window to act as titlebar, but from briefly disassembling quicktime/facetime they seem to use a NSThemeFrame subclass.

Comment: Also I saw your FOTWindow project, but that only seems to allow a fixed background color, basically I want to have the titlebar above an openglview.

Comment: Actually I think I figured out one way - extending the FOTWindow project I saw that if you stuff the entire gl view as a subview of `FOTWindowFrame` (i.e. fullcontentview) then it seems to work: the close buttons draw over the glview. In order for this to work the parent frame (and thus) glview has to be layer backed though, it won't work with a non layer-backed glview, which makes sense since opengl used to be handled specially and given its own surface.

Comment: There is another possible hack where you use obscure `NSOpenGLCPSurfaceOrder` to render _under_ the window, then make the window transparent and let the compositor do the blending for you, which also seems to work. But I saw some occasional crashes, not sure if due to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this either as mentioned in the comments to your question using some private API - you, however, won't be able to submit that app to the AppStore.

Other solution is to get `[[myWindow contentView] superview]` - which gets you the aforementioned `NSThemeView` instance. All you need to do then is to search the subviews of the view's (actually called a frame view) subviews for any instances of NSTextField and modify those. Note that the hierarchy of these private views may change with each release of OS X, potentially broking your code.

The probably best solution is to subclass (only subclass, no other customization) `NSWindow` and implement the `-title` and `-setTitle:` methods - for each window, you'd set the actual title to `@""` (by calling `[super setTitle:@""]`) and then place your own, programmatically created, `NSTextField` instance into the frame view (i.e. `[[[self contentView] superview] addSubview:myTextField]`, where `myTextField` is the text field. You need to figure out the exact placement, etc. of the field, but that's the easiest part.