# How to Change Color of NSWindow Title Bar in OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, titlebar

After a Long search regarding the `NSWindow` title bar color and title color, i have found a easy drawing solution. I posting this to share my knowledge.

Comment: Link to the [NSWindow documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow) in case anyone else comes here by accident wondering what it is.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sub class a `NSView` with name `MyTitleView` and add the following code

```
- (void)drawString:(NSString *)string inRect:(NSRect)rect {
    static NSDictionary *att = nil;
    if (!att) {
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
        [style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
        [style setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
        att = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,[NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
        [style release];

    }

    NSRect titlebarRect = NSMakeRect(rect.origin.x+20, rect.origin.y-4, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);


    [string drawInRect:titlebarRect withAttributes:att];
}


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect windowFrame = [NSWindow  frameRectForContentRect:[[[self window] contentView] bounds] styleMask:[[self window] styleMask]];
    NSRect contentBounds = [[[self window] contentView] bounds];

    NSRect titlebarRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, windowFrame.size.height - contentBounds.size.height);
    titlebarRect.origin.y = self.bounds.size.height - titlebarRect.size.height;

    NSRect topHalf, bottomHalf;
    NSDivideRect(titlebarRect, &topHalf, &bottomHalf, floor(titlebarRect.size.height / 2.0), NSMaxYEdge);

    NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds xRadius:4.0 yRadius:4.0];
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:titlebarRect] addClip];



    NSGradient * gradient1 = [[[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:1.0] endingColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1 alpha:1.0]] autorelease];
    NSGradient * gradient2 = [[[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1 alpha:1.0] endingColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0 alpha:1.0]] autorelease];

  [path addClip];


//    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.00 alpha:1.0] set];
//   [path fill];


   [gradient1 drawInRect:topHalf angle:270.0];
    [gradient2 drawInRect:bottomHalf angle:270.0];

    [[NSColor blackColor] set];
    NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0, -4, self.bounds.size.width, 1.0));


    [self drawString:@"My Title" inRect:titlebarRect];


}
```

In appDelegate Import the class `MyTitleView` and add the following code

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSRect boundsRect = [[[_window contentView] superview] bounds];
    BlackTitlebarView * titleview = [[BlackTitlebarView alloc] initWithFrame:boundsRect];
    [titleview setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];

    [[[_window contentView] superview] addSubview:titleview positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:[[[[_window contentView] superview] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Comment: This absolutely works, but Apple does note that as of Yosemite: "New since WWDC seed: NSWindow has never supported clients adding subviews to anything other than the contentView. Some applications would add subviews to the contentView.superview (also known as the border view of the window). NSWindow will now log when it detects this scenario: "NSWindow warning: adding an unknown subview:". Applications doing this will need to fix this problem, as it prevents new features on 10.10 from working properly. See titlebarAccessoryViewControllers for official API."

Answer (score 27):

There is a much easier way to do this. I've read that you can change a window's appearance to "textured" in a Storyboard / .xib file, but that doesn't work completely (titlebar color is mottled). However, you can change the color in your code with only two lines:

```
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true // gives it "flat" look
window.backgroundColor = <NSColor> // set the background color
```

Comment: @Tommy Yeah no problem.

Comment: This is the simplest and more elegant way. Thank you.

Comment: there is one flaw with this approach: when you want to present a sheet modal from that window, the sheet would descend from the top edge of the window, not from below the titlebar...

Comment: @Lvsti Hmmm.. I never had the need to present a sheet modal with my project, so I don't know what to do about that. I just figured I'd share what I ran into so people didn't have to smash their heads into walls copying a hundred lines of Objective-C from above. :/

Comment: This is awesome, but if I set it to a dark color, the window title is still black, and very hard to read. Any way to set the color of the window's title?

Comment: No idea. If you're okay with a dark theme altogether, you can set the theme of the window to the constant NSDarkVibrant or something like that. Don't remember the exact name but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: another flaw with this approach is, that the modal sheet to edit a toolbar will open directly above the toolbar that is to be edited.

Comment: But this doesn't change the color of TextField of the titlebar.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yeah I’ve heard it has a couple drawbacks, it is a bit of a hack. I didn’t work much on Mac applications so I have no clue how to do it properly. Maybe you can set the color of the title text field separately?

Answer (score 1):

No Warning message on OSX 10.10. like that

**NSView *windowTopView = [[_window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton] superview];**

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

NSRect boundsRect = [windowTopView bounds];

NSView *windowTopView = [[_window standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton] superview];
BTitleView * titleview = [[BTitleView alloc] initWithFrame:boundsRect];
[titleview setTitleImagePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Top1-01" ofType:@"bmp"]] ;
[titleview setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
[windowTopView addSubview:titleview positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:[[windowTopView subviews] objectAtIndex:0]];

//addTitlebarAccessoryViewController
NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController *dummyTitlebarAccessoryViewController;
NSView * logoview = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 10, 11)];
dummyTitlebarAccessoryViewController = [NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController new];
dummyTitlebarAccessoryViewController.view = logoview;
dummyTitlebarAccessoryViewController.fullScreenMinHeight = 0;
[_window addTitlebarAccessoryViewController:dummyTitlebarAccessoryViewController];


}
```